# jszip upload zip from formdata when created - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, form-data, jszip

The request is basic but i get stuck. I am working on an angular project.
The idea is to **load multiple image files into a zip and then upload the zip**, using JSzip.

1/ loading the multiple image files is okay

```
var zipdoc = new JSZIP();
zipdoc.file(myfile[x].name,myfile[x]);
zipdoc.generateAsync();
```

2/ **issue is to pass the zipfile to the fromData with the append function**

```
var myFormData= new FormData();
myFormData.append('userfile',zipdoc);
```

This section is not working at all. Any idea ?

Please let me know

Rgds

Answer (score 3):

[FormData#append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) accepts a string or a blob, you just need to generate one:

```
zipdoc.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(blob) {
  var myFormData = new FormData();
  myFormData.append('userfile', blob);
});
```